# Moving itunes from windows to mac

Tags: windows-7, macos, itunes

I tried copying my itunes folder from windows to mac and then running import in the mac, but all I have is my music and no playlists like I had in the Windows machine.

How can I get my library back how it was in the mac?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163601/85275 - you need to duplicate your *exact* hierarchy first except for top location, then use any type of search & replace to change the 'root' paths from C:/somewhere to 'myHD name/somewhere' then follow the rest to do the import.

Comment: @Tetsujin oh dear why can't Apple sort this mess. I might just stick to windows then. Thx

Comment: It works well on Mac & Apple doesn't care about Windows ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to migrate your iTunes library to another computer.

I have used Home Sharing successfully. The official help from apple for using Home Sharing this way is at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201976

1. Ensure both computers are on the same network.
2. Open iTunes on both computers.
3. Ensure both computers are signed into the same iTunes account and turn on Home Sharing.
4. On the destination computer, go to Shared Libraries and choose "Items not in my library" so you don't accidentally duplicate any items.

If you just want to use an external drive to copy your content between computers, Apple has official help to do so at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204318

Comment: The first method is only any good if both computers are running iTunes at that moment. The second only works if you are moving Mac>Mac or Win>Win, not if you move cross-platform.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for clarifying. I did mention that the first method does require iTunes to be running on both, but I didn't think about the issues in moving cross platform with an external drive. Is that the source of the problem in the OP?

Comment: The source of the problem is that iTunes uses an absolute path reference, so moving PC>Mac or vice versa means you have to go through the entire xml file, changing C:/Users/[username]/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/[album/song] to /Users/[username]/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/[album/song]  **Then** the quick way to import it without taking forever is to cleverly 'break' the associated .ita file which forces a fast rebuild.

Comment: This is so complex